# How to use SumByColor across multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, vba

I use the formula `SumByColor` and want to add the values of cells with the same color across multiple sheets.

```
=SumByColor(A2;'Project 1:Project 3'!B3:B28)
```

I tried the above formula, but get `#VALUE` returned.

If I do `=SumByColor(A2;'Project 1'!B3:B28)+SumByColor(A2;'Project 2'!B3:B28)` etc it works but I have > 15 sheets so it becomes a very long formula.

I used this VBA:

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, SumRange As Range)
Application.Volatile
Dim ICol As Integer
Dim TCell As Range
ICol = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
For Each TCell In SumRange
If ICol = TCell.Interior.ColorIndex Then
SumByColor = SumByColor + TCell.Value
End If
Next TCell
End Function
```

Comment: What is the code you are using for `SumByColor`? Wondering if it will work as a 3-d formula...

Comment: `SumByColor` is a user defined function, not a standard formula, so with out seeing the code behind the UDF we can not help, but most likely the code is not coded in a way to use arrays.

Comment: You will need to write code that takes the two end sheets and range as separate criteria and iterate the sheets in the code.  that short hand will not work with this function.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not an expert so I didn't add the iteration to the code but used my initial repeat of the formula and this works for now!